# Algorithm for client validation?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, security, client-server

Here is what I am trying to do.

I have a game and a server executable. The clients connect to the server to play.

The concern I currently have is that someone might use telnet or something to simulate a client.

Currently, the user only sends a simply hello string after they are connected and if it is correct I accept data from them.

I have tried to use certificates / ssl without success so I am trying to figure out an effective way to know if a game client is really a client.

Simply put, what would be an effective way to validate the client?

I am not concerned with a man in the middle attack since the users do not login nor provide passwords, just a session name.

I have thought of the possibility of the server sending a fixed length random string, then the client modifies this string with an algorithm, then sends it back.

I am wondering if there are better more clever ways than that.

I do actually have a certificate for my server, it is a pfx, if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but if the users don't provide usernames/passwords, what's the point of securing your server? If anyone can connect, there's no point for anyone to emulate a client.

Comment: @PawełStawarz I agree but, if they can impersonate a client, they might send malformed game messages that might freeze up or crash the server.

Comment: If you don't have messages that command the server to crash or freeze, they can't. Hovewer they can DoS or "Ping of Death" you, and if that's the case, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Milo You think your problem is "*how to ensure the server can trust the client*" but the fact is, you can't ensure it. Your whole question is simply misled. You  **must** design your server in a way that it doesn't, ever trust its clients. Actually, any sane server must be extremely paranoid about the data it gets from its clients.

Comment: I am with syam on this. While testing your connection for apparent validity might yeild a little benefit, you still need to assume they are enemies, and do basic error checking and only accept input of a form that you want and can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its intrinsically difficult as a problem. Certainly there is no software you can write, that could run on a foriegn machine, that can proves its the program you wrote in an un-tampered form.

Still, there is some simple challenge response stuff you ca do to improve things.

Lets assume your client and your server share a secret (your writing it, so they can, though being software it wont be very secret.) Lets also assume you have  ahandy crypt or hashing library (for things like a SHA-1 hash) Then:

- Server send challenge, including a nonce (eg the time + random number).
- Client sends a response, which includes a secure hash of (nonce + secret)
- Server know the nonce and the secret, so they can check the hash received is correct, and thus can confirm the "client" also knows the secret.

This is a basic symmetric validation scheme.